# How to use aws to send location of android device as an object to another app on another android device

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, android-studio, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am developing an app for the firedepartment of my town, i was very comfortable using parse as a back end service and then i got this warning that parse was disappearing by 2017, i am getting started using amazon web services as a back end as a service eprovider, yet i find mainly confusing information, for starters aws has over 50 or so different services and im overwellmed with information, even finding useful info for the cognito service is hard, i am also using the google maps api to develop this aplication and i intend to have the user app get the location coordinates (latitude, longitude) with no problems, now the issue here is to store this information in an object and send it through the aws server and then from there to another "receiver" app, that will then display such locations in a map in real time.

Comment: You can deploy a web service application in AWS that can store the data. In addition to that, [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm) can be a route you can use to send data from the server to the other receiver app. For example, if an entry is added in the database, you'll just send a downstream message to the appropriate client app's registration token. The client will then have to handle the data received and display it in real-time.

Comment: Any sample code? i know absolutely nothing about aws, for example i have no idea where to deploy a web service in aws, im even thinking to switch to google cloud.